# Batching a query to update because operation keeps timing out

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, batch-processing, querying

I am conducting the following data migration in SQLAlchemy and the operation keeps timing out, so I would like to batch the query in a way that allows me to complete the migration.

```
session = Session()
q = session.query(RawDocument)

for i in q:
    my_tf_dict = get_word_count(i)
    new_ob = ten_q()
    new_ob.tf_dict_phrases = my_tf_dict
    session.add(new_ob)
    del my_tf_dict

session.commit()
```

I think yield_per() may be an option? https://www.codepowered.com/manuals/SQLAlchemy-0.6.9-doc/html/orm/query.html

Also, maybe applying these methods could work?
https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/sql-api/batch-queries/

Table I am trying to update:

```
id     cik  tf_dict_phrase  factset_id                   key_name
1   706688                  000BFT-E    10q/706688_2005-5-10_10-Q
2   706688                  000BFT-E    10q/706688_2005-8-8_10-Q
3   706688                  000BFT-E    10q/706688_2005-11-8_10-Q
```

Comment: From the looks of it you're not updating, but inserting new rows. Usually you'd not commit between each and every change in the session, but after the loop has run its course.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to show the current format of the table I am trying to 'update'. The column I want to migrate the data to is 'tf_dict_phrase' matched by 'key_name'. Also, I moved the session.commit() outside the loop (I also updated it in the question). Thanks again.